# After upgrading to Python 3.5.6, Keras does not seem to work and it throws no errors about it

Tags: windows, keras, anaconda, python-3.5

I am using Anaconda 4.4.0 and I had an Anaconda version of Python installed as a conda environment. It was a version of the 3.5 branch (I think it was 3.5.2). Recently I installed Pytorch for Windows, which led to the upgrading of a few packages, including Python itself, which was upgraded to 3.5.6. Since then some of my files  will not run. What is worse is that they do not even display an error messages.

I checked the console and the Idle window but no error messages were thrown. So I tried the hard way and I placed print() statements throughout my code to see where the execution fails. I quickly figured that the issue is most probably caused by Keras. Whenever I even import that module, the Idle shell restarts without a warning. I only get the "Using TensorFlow backend." line and then it stops running. I also checked that not only when running a file, but also when running directly from a Python shell, importing Keras leads to the restarting of the shell.

I tried upgrading Keras to version 2.3.1, but to no avail. The issue persists. I also tried running from Python version 3.6.8, which is the "Base" of my Anaconda installation and not an installed environment. Any ideas as to who might be the culprit here?

I would like to avoid resorting to "radical" solutions, such as deleting everything and reinstalling or installing the newest version of Python, where I will have to reinstall every single package afresh, at least not until I have ruled out all other possible solutions.

Comment: Could you please share your current environment with `conda list`?

Comment: Here is a ink with images including my conda list. I couldn't post all of it as text because it was too long.[link](https://imgur.com/a/M4b0xGb)